# php how do I grab the date of oldest item in rss feed

Tags: php, rss, twitter

using simplexml to parse a feed, but I want to grab the date of the oldest item in the feed. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks

$rss = simplexml_load_file("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=foobar&rpp=100&page=1");

Comment: Are the entries sorted, i.e. do you want to grab the last <entry> element in the feed?

Comment: yes the last entry->published

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to get the last `<entry>`element (in [document-order](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-document-order)) you can use [SimpleXMLElement::xpath()](http://docs.php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) and the last() function
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ says:

> child::para[position()=last()] selects the last para child of the context node

e.g.

```
$url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=foobar&rpp=100&page=1"; 
$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);
$feed->registerXPathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

$entry = $feed->xpath('//atom:entry[position()=last()]');
if ( isset($entry[0]) ) {
  $entry = $entry[0];
}
else {
  die('not found');
}
var_dump($entry);
```

`[position()=last()]` can be shortened to `[last()]`

If the oldest entry is not the last entry in document-order, you'll need something else.

Comment: there is a stray ")" in there, but once I removed it the code worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. First get all items from RSS feed and store them in array something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php).
2. [Now sort array by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php/597869#597869).
3. Get the first/last result depending on your sorting order.