# How do I sort this array by this value?

Tags: php

How can I sort this array in PHP? I want to have the most recent dates first. I can't do the sort in MySQL as the date field is coming from several different tables. Three rows shown here - there are more than 600 in total.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        Translator => Array
            (
                [id] => 1482
                [name] => Jane Doe
                [last_project] => (null)
            )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        Translator => Array
            (
                [id] => 1024
                [name] => John Doe
                [last_project] => 2013-06-25
            )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (           
        Translator => Array
            (
                [id] => 32
                [name] => Tom Doe
                [last_project] => 2009-07-10
             )
        )
)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Sort a multidimensional array by element containing date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date)

Comment: show us the SQL Query, i'm sure it is sortable on the project if it spits out this array as a result...

Comment: I don't think so - I do one query to fetch all translators. Then loop through the results to find the most recent project date from one table. If no result found in that table, I do a second query to find the most recent project date from another table.

Comment: and even if the result is coming for multiple different tables, I still think it's sortable by the DB, if you know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a["last_project"]) - strtotime($b["last_project"]);
}
usort($array, "sortFunction");
```

Taken from [PHP order array by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401714/php-order-array-by-date)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I edited the form of my array above and had to edit the code here as well (added ['Translator'] in the callback function. Also had to reverse the array to get most recent first.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortByDate($a, $b) {
    return $a['last_project'] - $b['last_project'];
}

usort($myArray, 'sortByDate');
```