# How to sort a array of dates in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of date like

```
    a[0]=>2013-10-05
    a[1]=>2013-10-25
    a[2]=>2013-10-15
    a[3]=>2013-10-28
```

I want to sort in ascending order. 
How can i sort this?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: PHP has many functions for sorting arrays, see http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php Have you tried them? For example what did asort() return and why that did not match your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the default sort function as stated here: [Sort by Date](http://www.krio.me/sort-an-array-in-php-by-date/)

Or use a custom sort function like suggested here: [Custom Search Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401714/php-order-array-by-date)

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) 
{
    //$a and $b are two values from your array
    //Return a value > 0 then $a is greater than $b
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
usort($data, "sortFunction");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
$orderByDate = $my2 = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$row)
{
    $my2 = explode('-',$row[1]);
    $my_date2 = $my2[1].'-'.$my2[0].'-'.$my2[2];        
    $orderByDate[$key] = strtotime($my_date2);  
}    
array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_ASC, $data);
```