# Showing data in the form of json and print_r

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to form my array in order by date I have find my answer from this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401714/php-order-array-by-date) and it is show the desire result through this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401744/3151394) but when I use `print_r` or `json_encode` it just show me true.

I don't know why?

**The answer method:**

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a["date"]) - strtotime($b["date"]);
}
usort($worth_array, "sortFunction");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($worth_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Result:**

```
array(10) {
    [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["date"]=>
          string(10) "2014-06-03"
        ["worth"]=>
          int(1131)
      }
    [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["date"]=>
          string(10) "2014-06-04"
        ["worth"]=>
          int(4469)
      }
}
```

`print_r` method:

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a["date"]) - strtotime($b["date"]);
}
$worth_array_final = usort($worth_array, "sortFunction");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($worth_array_final);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Result: 1**

Comment: Usort : _Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure._ That's why `$worth_array_final` is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

`usort` returns a boolean (see [usort in php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)), and sorts the array passed as a reference. I.e. in your case `$worth_array` contains the sorted data and `$worth_array_final` only succes or not.