# Laravel: Displaying data from two tables in a view in a increasing Date

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have two tables. One is Sells Data and another is Bank Deposit Withdraw data. I can show data of sells table. and also can show data of banks. But I want to show the data like this

```
17 Nov 2017 Sells Data.....
16 Nov 2017 banks Data....
15 Nov 2017 Sells Data.....
15 Nov 2017 banks Data....
```

but now I get the data like this

```
15 Nov 2017 Sells Data.....
16 Nov 2017 Sells Data.....

15 Nov 2017 banks Data....
17 Nov 2017 banks Data....
```

How can I show the data as my desired one

codes:

```
$sell = Sells::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
$bank = Banks::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

getting data by this. But cannot show data as I want.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: paste your code here, so we all can understand more.

Comment: if your both table has relation then you can go with join query and get result order by date.

Comment: no relation between two tables. can I show like this

Comment: @Rits codes updated

Comment: first of all `merge` both the array and then make sorting on array by column with array function `array_sort_by_column($array, 'column name');`

Comment: check this it might be helps you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401714/php-order-array-by-date)

Answer (score 0):

if both tables have exact same colums, you can do it with `union`:

```
$sells = DB::table('sells')->select('*');
$banks = DB::table('banks')->select('*')
    ->union($sells)
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

but if they are not the same, you must select the same colums:

```
$sells= DB::table("sells")
    ->select("sells.name"
      ,"sells.price"
      ,"sells.created_at");
$banks = DB::table("banks")
    ->select("banks.name"
      ,"banks.price"
      ,"banks.created_at")
    ->unionAll($sells)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: the columns are totally different. in Sells there are customer_id, total_amount, paid, due columns and in Bank there are bank_id,withdraw,deposit columns

Comment: @KapilPaul i'm afraid you can't do anything about in then!

Comment: oh.. thanks for your help. is there any other loop that i can execute