# How one can sort an array of values by year and month in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a date array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php)

I want to sort out the array of values by year and month, I've attached my code here,
Year is sorting in descending in my script, i want to sort out year by ascending order,

```
<?php
$array = array("2011-September_38","2011-June_4","2010-November_9","2011-November_29","2010-December_19");
function monthCompare($a, $b) {
$count = substr($a,strpos($a,'_'));
$count =strlen($count);
$count1 = substr($b,strpos($b,'_'));
$count1 =strlen($count1);
    $a = strtolower(substr($a,5,-$count));
    $b = strtolower(substr($b,5,-$count1));


 $months = array(
        'january'=> 1,
        'february'=> 2,
        'march'=>3,
        'april'=>4,
        'may'=>5,
        'june'=>6,
        'july'=>7,
        'august'=>8,
        'september'=>9,
        'october'=>10,
        'november'=>11,
        'december'=>12
     );
        if($a == $b)
            return 0;
        if(!isset($months[$a]) || !isset($months[$b]))
            return $a > $b;
        return ($months[$a] > $months[$b]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    usort($array, "monthCompare");
    print_r($array);
    ?>
```

**Actual output:**

```
  Array
(
    [0] => 2011-June_4
    [1] => 2010-Marh_19
    [2] => 2011-September_38
    [3] => 2010-November_9
    [4] => 2011-November_29
)
```

**Required output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 2010-Marh_19 
        [1] => 2010-November_9 
        [2] => 2011-June_4 
        [3] => 2011-September_38
        [4] => 2011-November_29 )
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to me a duplicate of the linked question. OP's array has YYYY-Month_ID format and not actually a legal date.

Comment: yes but why they closed my question without verifying fully?

Comment: how to reopen this question? i want to get a good solution

Comment: http://codepad.org/7NoJIYoW i've wrote separate functions for year sorting and month sorting. the problem is either one only possible to sort. can anyone help to bind these two functions together for sorting  year then month.code is in the link.

Comment: I agree that your question should not have been closed. Please create another question and I will post a much simple answer to your problem there.

Comment: ok if I post another same question means, will the system block my questioning option?

Comment: hi anubhava, http://codepad.org/eSKlcPMF   could you bind two functions that used in my code. I've attached my link, please solve this in codepad.org

Comment: I can very well provide you solution on codepad but that just defeats idea of stackoverflow community where previously answered questions are there to help out other visitors. So I would request you to create a question and I will post my answer immediately.

Comment: ok, i provide you the link of stackoverflow:

Comment: anubhava, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355062/how-to-sort-particular-strings-from-an-array-of-values-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a custom sort function, something like this.

```
var months = new Array(12);
months['Jan'] = 1;
months['Feb'] = 2;
months['Mar'] = 3;
months['Apr'] = 4;
months['May'] = 5;
months['Jun'] = 6;
months['Jul'] = 7;
months['Aug'] = 8;
months['Sep'] = 9;
months['Oct'] = 10;
months['Nov'] = 11;
months['Dec'] = 12;

function sortDate(a,b)
  {
var m1 = a.substring(0,3);
var y1 = a.substring(4);
var m2 = b.substring(0,3);
var y2 = b.substring(4);    

if(Number(y1)>Number(y2)) {
    return 1;
} else if(Number(y1)<Number(y2)) {
    return -1;
} else {
    if(months[m1]>months[m2]) {
        return 1;
    } else if(months[m1]<months[m2]) {
        return -1;
    }
}

return 0;
   }

var myArray = ['Oct/08', 'Jan/09', 'Mar/09', 'May/07', 'Apr/08', 'Dec/06'];
alert(myArray.sort(sortDate));
```

Comment: could you provide this as a php script?

Comment: you have got to be kidding..he just HANDED it to you!

Answer (score 0):

[You can Check This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php) :-

Use the ISO (yyyy-mm-dd) format rather than the "english" format, and then just use the ksort function to get them in the right order.

There's no need to remove the hyphens, ksort will do an alphanumeric comparison on the string keys, and the yyyy-mm-dd format works perfectly well as the lexical order is the same as the actual date order.

Comment: this is not yyy-mm-dd format, it has year and month only, remaining is ID,thats separated by '_'

Comment: i am getting this value like this only, i want to sort out by year and months from english format value.