# how to sort particular strings from an array of values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, arraylist

```
$array = array("2011-September_38","2011-June_4","2010-November_9","2011-November_29","2010-December_19");
```

i want to sort this array strings as following,  it should sort the year first, then it should sort the month,

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [0] => 2010-Marh_19 
        [1] => 2010-November_9 
        [2] => 2011-June_4 
        [3] => 2011-September_38
        [4] => 2011-November_29 )
```

I've tried something, could anyone bind my function to sort year then month http://codepad.org/skEiUkTC

Comment: btw `"2010-Marh_19"` is not in your array so it can't be in desired output :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$array = array("2011-September_38","2011-June_4","2010-November_9","2011-November_29","2010-December_19");
function monthCompare($a, $b) {
   $da = strtotime(strstr($a, '_', true));
   $db = strtotime(strstr($b, '_', true));
   return $da > $db;
}
usort($array, "monthCompare");
print_r($array);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2010-November_9
    [1] => 2010-December_19
    [2] => 2011-June_4
    [3] => 2011-September_38
    [4] => 2011-November_29
)
```

Comment: @balaji: Please see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php. As per this manual: `5.3.0  Added the optional parameter before_needle.` which means you need to have at least php ver 5.3.0 to use this additional argument in strstr function. If you don't have php 5.3.0 or above pls let me know, I can provide you alternative solution.

Comment: I discovered the DateTime class when trying to solve this issue and i would recommend you take a look at it also, it gives you the ability to work with time in a very clean way and not by messing around with strstr inside strtotime :-)

Comment: thanks anubhava, your concept is very simple, i was very confusing with my older code, now its working fine, i replaced your "strstr" with "substr" function, http://codepad.org/JELYk99G, i've edited your answer. now its ok..

Comment: Thanks that you liked it. However consider this solution for PHP ver < 5.3.0: http://codepad.org/tmwnyNtd

Answer (score 1):

So a simple solution to this, is to turn each of the values into a objects with [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), sort them, and then outputting the values again.

Before i saw this question i had never played with DateTime objects, but they are awesome and easy to work with, and `createFromFormat` makes perfectly sense.

```
$array = array("2011-September_30","2011-June_4","2010-November_9","2011-November_29","2010-December_19");

foreach($array as $item)
{
    $timestamps[] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-F_d',$item);
}

sort($timestamps);

foreach($timestamps as $timestamp)
{
    $newarray[] = $timestamp->format('Y-F_d');
}
```

will give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2010-November_09
    [1] => 2010-December_19
    [2] => 2011-June_04
    [3] => 2011-September_30
    [4] => 2011-November_29
)
```

Comment: As per the OP array element are not a date in the `YYYY-Month_dd` format. It is actually `YYYY-Month_ID` where ID can be any number like 68 or 95.

Comment: You must know the specific problem, as i was not able to read such from the question.

Comment: Not your fault, actually OP earlier left a comment indicating that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351929/how-one-can-sort-an-array-of-values-by-year-and-month-in-php

Comment: hi bro, the last digit is not date, its ID. thanks for your answer.nice concept.