# Need assistance with a usort requirement

Tags: php, date, usort

I've taken a look at a few googles and actually found this stack too: [How to sort a date array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php)

I'ts on the same wave length but i'm not sure i get it clearly. I've read over the phpnet documentation too... As I said, i'm feeling shakey from it.

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2012-06-06 21:26:25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2012-06-06 21:23:45
        )

)
```

And I basically need to sort this array so that they are in date order.
How does this call back function work for usort? Any examples would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MySort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['created'] == $b['created']) return 0;
    return $a['created'] < $b['created'] ? -1 : 1;
}
```

then use...

```
usort($myarray, "MySort");
```

Comment: `$a['created']` is a string that represents a date.

Comment: Yes, but strtotime does not need to be performed as it is in yyyy-mm-dd format, so its sorted by Year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds respectively.

Comment: As long as all the months/days are zero padded, then you're fine.  Otherwise `'5'>'06'`.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I have now written another 2 sorts for other reasons and they are all working... I think i've grasped it. Cheers for simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

`usort` just lets you sort using your own criteria.  You can just simply do this:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    $a = strtotime($a['created']);
    $b = strtotime($b['created']);
    return $a-$b;
});
```