# Possible to sort complex PHP for loop

Tags: php, sorting, for-loop

Is it possible to sort a complex for loop? Would I store the values in an array and then sort by that?

This is the for loop I'm working with, I would like to sort by the date & time of the events I'm pulling through

```
foreach ($recurring_events as $recurring_event):
    if ($recurring_event->period == 'week') { 
        $StartDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateStart);
        $EndDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateEnd);
        $TotalDays = round(($EndDate-$StartDate)/(60*60*24*7));
        for($i=0; $i<($TotalDays-1); $i++) {
            $StartDate += (60*60*24*7);
            if (date('WMY', $StartDate) == date('WMY')) {
                echo '<div class="col-12">';

                echo '<strong>Event Name:</strong> ' . $event->EventName . '<br /><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('l, F j o',$StartDate) . '<br /><strong>Start Time:</strong> ' . date('g:i a',strtotime($event->RequestTimeStart));

                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Is `$recurring_event` supposed to be `$event`?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse no, this is just a snippet of a lot bigger code :)

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you're sorting by then - `$StartDate` is going to be the same every time you go round the loop.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse $StartDate is being increased by a week every time in the loop so it is not the same.

Comment: what you want sort by aces or desc?

Comment: I'd like to do it by DESC. For example.. Jan 1st Event at 6PM, Jan 1st Event at 8PM, Jan 2nd Event at 8AM, Jan 2nd Event at 9PM, Jan 3rd Event at 6PM.

Comment: @rohitarora any idea how to accomplish the above comment?

Comment: but this is aces i think because you want in line wise.And do you want to sort the re-occuring event or all events?

Comment: @rohitarora I would like to sort all of the events. The other events can be sorted by the call to the database. But the related ones are tricky because they aren't coming from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($recurring_events as $recurring_event):
    if ($recurring_event->period == 'week') { 
        $StartDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateStart);
        $EndDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateEnd);
        $TotalDays = round(($EndDate-$StartDate)/(60*60*24*7));
        for($i=0; $i<($TotalDays-1); $i++) {
            $EndDate -= (60*60*24*7);
            if (date('WMY', $StartDate) == date('WMY')) {
                echo '<div class="col-12">';

                echo '<strong>Event Name:</strong> ' . $event->EventName . '<br /><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('l, F j o',$StartDate) . '<br /><strong>Start Time:</strong> ' . date('g:i a',strtotime($event->RequestTimeStart));

                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
endforeach;
```

try this start from the end date and minus it.if you want it ti be in decsnding sorry if i dint understood you question

Comment: I tried it out with no luck :( it is producing multiples of each date. When trying to put the results in an array, I am ending up with empty values. If there is a way to sort the array in the format I'm getting it, I think that would work. Check out how it looks here: http://beta.revival.tv/test/

Comment: i think there is something with the code itself can you please write the complete code so i can decend you whole data..

Comment: do you have an email address I can send it to you at? Just to keep this clean and not overwhelming with too much info.

Comment: rohit.rohitseju@gmail.com you can mail me.

Answer (score 2):

put it in an array, then refer to this post for how to sort by date

[How to sort a date array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your results into an array, then sort it, then output it.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($recurring_events as $recurring_event):
    if ($recurring_event->period == 'week') { 
        $StartDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateStart);
        $EndDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateEnd);
        $TotalDays = round(($EndDate-$StartDate)/(60*60*24*7));
        for($i=0; $i<($TotalDays-1); $i++) {
            $StartDate += (60*60*24*7);
            if (date('WMY', $StartDate) == date('WMY')) { //$StartDate >= strtotime('now') &&
                $output[$StartDate] .= '<div class="col-12">';

                $output[$StartDate] .='<strong>Event Name:</strong> ' . $event->EventName . '<br /><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('l, F j o',$StartDate) . '<br /><strong>Start Time:</strong> ' . date('g:i a',strtotime($event->RequestTimeStart));

                $output[$StartDate] .='</div>';
            }
        }
    }
endforeach;
```

And then use sort

```
sort($output);
```

Assuming that your StartDate is the date you need (then it should be an unix timestampe?)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: I will also need to sort by time. So just specify a time variable as well in the array? I can pull the time variable through as well so it will be populated. So something like Something like $output[$StartDate, $StartTime]?

Comment: This does not work, it is storing it in multiple arrays, not a single array.

Comment: So the second parameter of the date function is a timestamp, an integer, so the value of $StartDate will include the time as well as the date. When sorted it will sort date and time. To clarify, the timestamp is the number of seconds passed since Jan 1st 1970, for example: 1360031642

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to sort the data while looping round it to output it. Instead, sort the data, then loop round the sorted data to output.

A useful function is [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) which takes an array and uses a function you define to sort it:

```
function sortEvents($a, $b) {
   if (strtotime($a->RequestDateStart) == strtotime($b->RequestDateStart)) {
      return 0;
   }
   return ($a->RequestDateStart < $b->RequestDateStart) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($recurring_events,'sortEvents');
```

Comment: I've been looking more into this function, but will that work with what I am trying to do? I am using a for loop to build my results so I can't sort before hand. It would have to be after somehow.

Comment: Build, Sort, Output. Don't mix them. Looping 3 times is not expensive.