# Sorting multiple arrays by date using uasort function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I have multiple arrays in the following format:

```
Array ( 
[1283990400] => info

[1285804800] => info

[1286409600] => info
)
```

you can see the output here: http://beta.revival.tv/test/

I am trying to sort all the arrays together by date. I have stored the timestamp in the key of the array, but I am unsure of how to use the uasort function to accomplish what I want.

From what I have read this is the function I should be using. I have read countless articles explaining it for really simple arrays, but I don't understand how I can apply it here.

I have already tried ksort with no luck because I am trying to sort all the arrays as a whole, not individually.

I also have already read the following post here giving me the idea to use uasort: [Possible to sort complex PHP for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697649/possible-to-sort-complex-php-for-loop/14786062#comment20738112_14786062)

Comment: Looks like job for http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php rather than uasort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `ksort`.

> Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is useful mainly for associative arrays.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Comment: This will not work with what I want to do though. I have multiple arrays that need to be sorted as a whole, not individually.

Comment: @ftntravis So merge them, then do a `ksort`?

Comment: Can I pass an array to array_merge though? Or how would I go about merging this output: http://beta.revival.tv/test/

Comment: @ftntravis Check out [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for `array_merge`.