# Sort array of dates which are formatted as d/m/Y

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I have an associative array in PHP where the key is a string and the value is a date.

Example `"fileid" => "10/10/2013".`

I want to be able to sort them by the most recent date.

I have no idea how I would do this, any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I have now used the usort function.

However my output is as follows:

```
02/09/2013
03/09/2013
03/10/2013
04/07/2013
04/09/2013
09/09/2013
11/09/2013
13/06/2013
13/08/2013
```

It is only sorting by the first two numbers, I want it to sort for the full date, What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
usort($filesWithDates,"my_sort");
    foreach ($filesWithDates as &$value) {
        echo $value."<br/>";
}

function my_sort($a,$b)
{
    if ($a==$b) return 0;
    return ($a<$b)?-1:1;
}
```

Comment: Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) with a custom compare function.

Comment: @ComFreek Right, but he'll probably want the `uasort()` variant.

Comment: this question is very similar to the linked one, but not really a duplicate. I wouldn't have marked it as such

Comment: The answers from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php are not useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are not instantly compared as strings because they are not in a descending unit format (`Y-m-d`).

For this reason, you will need to allow `strtotime()` to parse the strings into values that can be easily sorted.  There is an extra step in this because `strtotime()` will incorrectly parse your `d/m/Y` format as American `m/d/Y`.  To resolve this issue, replace the forward slashes with hyphen to convert the format to European -- `strtotime()` will correctly parse this.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HEg1U))

```
$array = [
    '02/09/2013',
    '03/09/2013',
    '03/10/2013',
    '04/07/2013',
    '04/09/2013',
    '09/09/2013',
    '11/09/2013',
    '13/06/2013',
    '13/08/2013',
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) { return strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $a)) <=> strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $b));});

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '13/06/2013',
  1 => '04/07/2013',
  2 => '13/08/2013',
  3 => '02/09/2013',
  4 => '03/09/2013',
  5 => '04/09/2013',
  6 => '09/09/2013',
  7 => '11/09/2013',
  8 => '03/10/2013',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ISO dates (e.g., `2013-10-10`, or `2014-12-31`) you simply need an `asort()`