# show duplicates in results with different dates

Tags: php, mysql

I need help. I have a database table with open house data. I have open house date and next open house date columns. Currently I can make a search by date range and it will show me the all the open houses that include open dates and next open dates. What I want to do is when sorting by date, I want to duplicate the row if there's a next open date with that date, so when a person is scrolling down the list they will see that same open house but with next open date as a duplicate. What would be the best practices for this? currently I have just listing showing once with open date and next date. Please help. Thanks

MYSQL table:

> `` INSERT INTO `active_listings` (`ID`, `mls_id`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `price`, `total_apx_sqft`, `bedrooms`, `bathrooms`, `listing_agent`, `listing_agent_id`, `listing_agent_office`, `school_district`, `open_date`, `next_open_date`, `time_from`, `time_to`, `next_time_from`, `next_time_to`, `photo_url`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `map_quality`, `map_zoom_level`, `update_date`, `public_remarks`, `agent_email`, `agent_website`, `agent_image`, `virtual_tour`, `area_grid`, `sub_division`, `acres`, `year_built`, `directions`) 
>   VALUES
>   (1, '20144226', '1928 S Legacy Dr', 'Liberty Lk', 'WA', '99019', 270000, 1968, '4', '3', 'Karen Smith', '2245', 'Coldwell Banker', 'Central', '2014-12-20 00:00:00', '2014-12-21 00:00:00', '12:00 pm', '4:00 pm', '12:00 pm', '4:00 pm', NULL, '47.654011', '-117.114914', '0.95', '16', '2014-12-21 22:25:12', 'xxx', 'kar@gmail.com', 'www.sdf.com', NULL, '', 'A112/087', 'Parkside', '0', '2014', 'Liberty Lake Exit, right on Country Vista Dr.'); ``

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how does your table look like and while you're at it, can you show us an example of how it currently looks and how you'd like your list to look like?

Comment: I provided more info. I just want it like this but sort by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand well, you can simply remove "next_open_date" column, and insert one row for each open_date for the same house.

```
| house | open_date  |
| h1    | 2014-12-10 |
| h2    | 2014-12-11 |
| h1    | 2014-12-15 |
```

or (whith a little more work) use another table to store the dates.

```
houses table:                house open dates table:
| ID | house |               | house_id | open_date  |
| 1  | h1    |               |     1    | 2014-12-10 |
| 2  | h2    |               |     2    | 2014-12-11 |
                             |     1    | 2014-12-15 |
```

then INNER JOIN your select:

```
SELECT a.house, b.open_date FROM houses a INNER JOIN open_dates b ON a.id = b.house_id;
```

this will result in one row for each open_date.

Comment: I also need the next open date. Theres two, first open house date and then next open house date.

Comment: In my example you will have all open_dates. If you order by date, de second row will be the next_open_date.

Comment: if you can't change the database, you can duplicate your record wherever you are retrieving the results from DB. i guess it is an array. Then some examples of how you are doing it will be great for help you

Comment: that was my first thought, but how would I sort by date then?

Comment: Then you can try the solution of this topic to order your array by date. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php