# php array sorting issue

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi I want to sort array can any one tell me please here is array.
i want to sort it by date  as you can see there is data

> 2015-05-20
>
> 2015-06-06

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [schedule] => WEEKENDS [title] => 2015-05-20 [track] => 6:00 Pm - 9:20 Pm [days] => May 20, 21, 27, 28 June 3, 4 ) [2] => Array ( [schedule] => WEEKENDS [title] => 2015-05-23 [track] => 9:00 Am - 2:30 Pm [days] => May 23, 24 & May 30, 31 ) [3] => Array ( [schedule] => WEEKENDS [title] => 2015-06-6 [track] => Timing will posted soon... [days] => June 06, 07 & June 13, 14 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [schedule] => EVENINGS [title] => 2015-05-16 [track] => 9:00am
- 2:30pm [days] => May 16, 17, 18 & 19 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [schedule] => EVENINGS [title] => 2015-05-16 [track] => 9:00am - 2:30pm [days] => May 16, 17, 18 & 19 ) [2] => Array ( [schedule] => WEEKENDS [title] => 2015-05-25 [track] => 9:00am - 2:30pm [days] => May 16, 17, 18 & 19 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [schedule] => WEEKENDS [title] => 2015-06-30 [track] => 10:00am - 12:30pm [days] => June 2,4 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [schedule] => EVENINGS [title] => 2015-05-17 [track] => 9:00am - 2:30pm [days] => June 2,4,5,8 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [schedule] => 4DAYS [title] => 2015-05-18 [track] => 9:00am - 2:30pm [days] => May 16, 17, 18 & 19 ) )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a date array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php)

Comment: yeah i see this answer but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own sort function like this.

It sorts based on the value of the "title" key.

```
$array = array(
    array("title" => "2015-05-20",
        "schedule" => "WEEKENDS"
    ),
    array("title" => "2015-05-16",
        "schedule" => "WEEKENDS"
    )
);

function sortByTitle($a, $b) {
    return $a['title'] - $b['title'];
}

usort($array , 'sortByTitle');

print_r($array);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => 2015-05-16
            [schedule] => WEEKENDS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => 2015-05-20
            [schedule] => WEEKENDS
        )

)
```