# Sort Array by two dates and rules

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I'm building an events listing calendar. Events have a start date and an end date with dates stored in the format YYYYMMDD. The event listing is viewed by day and events can be on a single day, or span multiple days.

Events are currently stored in an array, with `start_date` and `end_date`

How can I:

- Move any events that start on the current date to the top of the
  array.
- Then sort the events by start date
- Then sort the events by end date

Have see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597863/how-to-sort-a-date-array-in-php#597869), but wandering how I can build up the logic above.

Comment: Do you want three types of sorting or all these rules in one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move any events that start on the current date to the top of the array, but leave others ordered as is!

```
$today = date('Ymd',strtotime('today'));
usort($events,function($a,$b) use($today){
  if($a['start_date'] === $today && $b['start_date'] != $today){return -1;}
  else if($b['start_date'] === $today && $a['start_date'] != $today){return 1;}
  else {return strnatcmp($a['start_date'],$b['start_date']);}
});
```

**or** sort the events by start date

```
usort($events,function($a,$b){
  return strnatcmp($a['start_date'],$b['start_date']);
});
```

**or** sort the events by end date

```
usort($events,function($a,$b){
  return strnatcmp($a['end_date'],$b['end_date']);
});
```

**EDIT** Some test data:

```
//example works best if today is 20170810
$events = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'a',
    'start_date' => '20170810',
    'end_date' => '20170811',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'b',
    'start_date' => '20170810',
    'end_date' => '20170810',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'c',
    'start_date' => '20170607',
    'end_date' => '20170608',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'd',
    'start_date' => '20170607',
    'end_date' => '20170607',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'e',
    'start_date' => '20170810',
    'end_date' => '20170812',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'f',
    'start_date' => '20170807',
    'end_date' => '20170817',
  ),
);
print_r($events);
```

**EDIT: All of them together:** Events are ordered by 'Are they starting today?', 'start_date', 'end_date'

```
$today = date('Ymd',strtotime('today'));
usort($events,function($a,$b) use($today){
  //one of them starts today
  if($a['start_date'] === $today && $b['start_date'] != $today){return -1;}
  else if($b['start_date'] === $today && $a['start_date'] != $today){return 1;}
  //both or neither start today, compare start_date
  else {
    if($a['start_date'] != $b['start_date']){
      //start_dates differ, order by them
      return strnatcmp($a['start_date'],$b['start_date']);
    } else {
      //start dates are the same, order by end_date
      return strnatcmp($a['end_date'],$b['end_date']);
    }
  }
});

print_r($events);
```

**EDIT: ONGOING** Events are ordered by 'Are they currently ongoing?', 'start_date', 'end_date'

```
$today = date('Ymd',strtotime('today'));
//function compares two elements to decide their position relative to each other
usort($events,function($a,$b) use($today){
  //check if event is currently ongoing
  //starts or ends today or today is between start and end
  $ongoing = function($event) use($today){
    //this is the simplest form I could think of for the check
    return (strnatcmp($event['start_date'],$today) < 1 && strnatcmp($today,$event['end_date']) < 1);
  };
  $startstoday = function($event) use($today){
    return $event['start_date'] === $today;
  };
  //only one of them is ongoing
  if($ongoing($a) && !$ongoing($b)){return -1;}
  else if($ongoing($b) && !$ongoing($a)){return 1;}
  //both or neither are ongoing, compare start_date
  else {
    if($a['start_date'] != $b['start_date']){
      //start_dates differ, order by them
      return strnatcmp($a['start_date'],$b['start_date']);
    } else {
      //start dates are the same, order by end_date
      return strnatcmp($a['end_date'],$b['end_date']);
    }
  }
});

print_r($events);
```

**EDIT: STARTING TODAY AND ONGOING** Events are ordered by 'Are they starting today?', 'Are they currently ongoing?', 'start_date', 'end_date'

```
$today = date('Ymd',strtotime('today'));
//function compares two elements to decide their position relative to each other
usort($events,function($a,$b) use($today){
  //check if event is currently ongoing
  //starts or ends today or today is between start and end
  $ongoing = function($event) use($today){
    //this is the simplest form I could think of for the check
    return (strnatcmp($event['start_date'],$today) < 1 && strnatcmp($today,$event['end_date']) < 1);
  };
  //only one of them is ongoing
  if($ongoing($a) && !$ongoing($b)){return -1;}
  else if($ongoing($b) && !$ongoing($a)){return 1;}
  //both are ongoing
  else if($ongoing($a) && $ongoing($b)){
    //one starts today
    if($a['start_date'] === $today && $b['start_date'] != $today){return -1;}
    else if($b['start_date'] === $today && $a['start_date'] != $today){return 1;}
    //both start today
    else if($a['start_date'] === $today && $b['start_date'] === $today){
      return strnatcmp($a['end_date'],$b['end_date']);
    }
    //none starts today
    else {
      if($a['start_date'] != $b['start_date']){
        //start_dates differ, order by them
        return strnatcmp($a['start_date'],$b['start_date']);
      } else {
        //start dates are the same, order by end_date
        return strnatcmp($a['end_date'],$b['end_date']);
      }
    }
  } else {
    //neither are ongoing, compare start_date
    if($a['start_date'] != $b['start_date']){
      //start_dates differ, order by them
      return strnatcmp($a['start_date'],$b['start_date']);
    } else {
      //start dates are the same, order by end_date
      return strnatcmp($a['end_date'],$b['end_date']);
    }
  }
});

print_r($events);
```

**AND THIS LAST ONE CAN BE SIMPLIFIED TO:**

```
$today = date('Ymd',strtotime('today'));
usort($events,function($a,$b) use($today){
  $ongoing = function($event) use($today){
    return (strnatcmp($event['start_date'],$today) < 1 && strnatcmp($today,$event['end_date']) < 1);
  };
  if($ongoing($a)){
    if(!$ongoing($b)){return -1;}
    else {
      if($a['start_date'] === $today && $b['start_date'] != $today){return -1;}
      else if($b['start_date'] === $today && $a['start_date'] != $today){return 1;}
    }
  } else if($ongoing($b)){return 1;}
  if($a['start_date'] != $b['start_date']){
    return strnatcmp($a['start_date'],$b['start_date']);
  } else {
    return strnatcmp($a['end_date'],$b['end_date']);
  }
});

print_r($events);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, makes sense - didn't think to just apply each sort after each other.

Comment: @addedlovely Keep in mind that each sorting undoes any previous ones. Did you want only one sorter with the three rules applied in descending order?

Comment: @addedlovely I added solutions with all rules combined and accounting for events currently ongoing.